# Interim way to handle https requests while SSL certificate is being arranged?

Tags: ssl, http, ssl-certificate, https

What can I do to handle `https` requests while an `SSL` certicate is being arranged?

The `https` requests are being made from a desktop app so there are no browsers involved.

Are there free certs I can put in without disrupting anything?

Comment: Why would you put the application into production if the supporting components weren't in place and ready?

Answer (score 1):

If a self signed wont work as suggested by nickw you can free cents from http://cert.startcom.org/

We have used them for quite a few websites that we want to secure without any issues

Answer (score 0):

Add a self signed certificate, a browser will complain (your app may or may not), but after acceptance it will work. If you search for self signed certificates, you can find many a tutorial like [this](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-and-install-an-apache-self-signed-certificate.html).

Comment: What is the app likely to do?

Comment: That's a really good question, it depends on what the programmers decided was appropriate. I've seen programs react differently, some are vocal about the certificate not being trusted (chrome being one) others can be told to trust it without further complaints (firefox). For sure the first time you connect it will say that the certificate is not trusted.